# How to remove column names from a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

```
  M = matrix(1:9,3,3)
colnames(M)=c('a','b','c')
```

Suppose I have a matrix `M` , with column names 'a','b','c'.  And I want to remove the names, so that M

```
M    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Rather than

```
       a     b    c
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't get the desired output, I get NA NA NA rather than [,1] [,2] [,3]

Comment: The code does not work for you?  It works fine for me...I am trying to get from a matrix with a ton of assigned names to a nameless one.  The reason is complicated. This should  be a fairly easy thing to do i'd think...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try

```
colnames(M) <- NULL
```

Using your example:

```
> M
#     a b c
#[1,] 1 4 7
#[2,] 2 5 8
#[3,] 3 6 9
> colnames(M) <- NULL
> M
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

However, if your data is stored in a data.frame instead of a matrix, this won't work. As explained in `?data.frame`:

> The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have unsupported results

If your data is stored as a data.frame (this can be checked with `class(my_data)`), you could try to convert it into a matrix with `M <- as.matrix(my_data)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 29):

I know it's been a while since this was asked, but seeing as it is a highly trafficked question, I thought this might be useful.

If you want to perform this action on `M` instead of its column names, you could try

```
M <- unname(M)
>M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

This would be more efficient if you want to pipe or nest the output into subsequent functions because `colnames` does not return `M`.

Comment: This also works well with piping, thank you1

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete row names use `row.names()` function

```
>M
      a b c
1[1,] 1 4 7
2[2,] 2 5 8
3[3,] 3 6 9

>row.names(M)<- NULL ; colnames(M)<- NULL
>M

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```