# How to get a matrix element without the column name in R?

Tags: r

This seems to be simple but I can't find the answer.
I combine two vectors using cbind().

```
> first = c(1:5)
> second = c(6:10)
> values = cbind(first,second)
```

When I want to retrieve a single element using values[1,2] I always get the column name in addition to the actual element.

```
> values[1,2]

second
6
```

How can I get the value without the column name?

I know I can remove the column names in the matrix like in this post: [How to remove column names from a matrix in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658793/how-to-remove-column-names-from-a-matrix-in-r) But how can I leave the matrix as is and only get the value I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `unname`

```
unname(values[1,2])
#[1] 6
```

Or `as.vector`

```
as.vector(values[1,2])
```

You can use the `[[` operator to extact a single element,

```
values[[1,2]]
# [1] 6
```